# Quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H=\{1,-1,i,-i\}$ be the subgroup of $G=\mathbb{C^\times}$ of fourth roots of unity. Describe the cosets of $H$ in $G$ explicitly. Is $G/H$ isomorphic to $G$?

I know we have to use first isomorphism theorem but I don't know how to to do this problem.

(Here $\mathbb{C^\times}$ is set of nonzero complex numbers with operation multiplication)

Comment: $H = F$, I assume?

Comment: @martini: That was a typo! Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**: (1) For $\lambda \in \def\Cs{\mathbb C^\times}\Cs$, can you compute $\lambda H =\{\lambda h \mid h \in H\}$, the coset of $\lambda$?

(2) For using the isomorphism theorem, you need an epimorphism $p \colon \Cs \to \Cs$ with kernel $H$. Can you think of one? As you write, $H$ consists of the forth roots of unity, so $h^4 = 1$ exactly for $h \in H$.

Comment: The cosets will be $a+bi(1)=\{a+bi\}$, $a+bi(-1)=\{-a-bi\}$, $a+bi(i)=\{ai-b\}$, $a+bi(-i)=\{-ai+b\}$.

For second part I can define a map $f: \mathbb{C^\times}\rightarrow  \mathbb{C^\times}$ by $f(a+bi)=b$.

Comment: @JamesBond: Neither is the map you define a morphism (it's not multiplicative), neither is it onto, nor is the kernel $H$. It isn't even a map $\mathbb C^\times \to \mathbb C^\times$ as $f(1) = 0$.

Comment: Ah! I see, I can define $f(a+bi)=a^2+b^2$ and that will get the job done, right?

Comment: This map is multiplicative, but not onto ... and its kernel is $S^1$ (the set of $z\in \mathbb C$ with modulus 1).

Comment: considering that it is 4th root of unity we can have $f(a+bi)=(a-bi)$ which is also surjective

Comment: @James: maybe try thinking in terms of the hint given by martini, as well as the fact the complex numbers are algebraically closed.

Comment: @james The last map to proposed has kernel 1 ... to be more explicit: You need a map that maps the forth roots of 1 to 1 ...

Answer (score 2):

> Let $\varphi: G= \mathbb C^\times \rightarrow G' = \mathbb C^\times$ so that $\varphi(x) = x^4$

$\varphi$ is a group homomorphism since

> $\varphi(ab) = (ab)^{4} = a^{4}b^{4} = \varphi(a)\varphi(b)$

$\varphi$ is surjective as $\varphi^{-1}(x) = x^{1/4}$

The $\text{ker}\, \varphi$ is the fiber of $1$.  Namely,

> $\text{ker}\, \varphi = \{\pm 1,\pm i  \} = H$

The cosets of $H$ in $G$ are the quotient group $G\,/\,H$.

By the First Isomorphism Theorem, $G\,/\,H$ is isomorphic to $G'=G$.

$\Box$

Comment: I'm confused here. How is $\phi$ surjective if Kernel contains more than one element?

Comment: In this case $G$ is not a finite group so it is not the case that $\displaystyle(G:H)=\frac{|G|}{|H|}$.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. How do we assert injection in such a case?

Comment: I suppose you are asking about surjectivity, not injectivity.  For every $x$ in the range $G'=\mathbb{C}^\times$, there exists element $a=x^{1/4}$ in the domain $G=\mathbb{C}^\times $ such that $\varphi(a)=a^4 = x$.  Hence $\varphi$ is surjective.